# iterator hasNext returns true but next throws exception

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashmap, set

I was just curious on how multiple iterators on a single object would behave and typed in the following code.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Test{
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1,"One");

    Iterator<Integer> it1 = map.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> it2 = map.keySet().iterator();

    it1.next();
    it1.remove();
    System.out.println(it2.hasNext());
    System.out.println(it2.next());

    System.out.println(map.get(1));
  }
}
```

The map is empty as expected But, i thought [`Iterator#hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()) would return `false`, but instead it returned `true` and [`Iterator#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) threw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

when a value is removed from a `Collection` using the `Iterator#remove` method shouldn't the other iterator's `hasNext` method return false, as there wouldn't be any value to be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`hasNext`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.HashIterator.hasNext%28%29) method only checks the `next` attribute:

```
public final boolean hasNext() {
  return next != null;
}
```

and the only method that modifies the `next` attribute are:

- the [`nextEntry`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.HashIterator.nextEntry%28%29) method
- and the [`remove`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.HashIterator.remove%28%29) method

Which means that if you a few `Iterator` instances pointing to the same collection instance only when you call one of the above two methods the Iterator will access the underlying collection and check whether its state has change.

Please note that if the underlying collection is modified the behavior of an iterator is **unspecified**, which means it might be changed and you should not depend on it.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the exact methods that changes the state of the object. +1 for that :)

Comment: i am wondering what would be in the next reference..? once remove is called on another iterator, it is removed from the underlying collection.. so what is `next` referring to..?

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) for `iterator.remove()` states:

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

And that is precisely what is happening in your code, the underlying collection is being modified for more than one iterator.